# Saving bitmap as 300dpi png

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to save a System.Drawing.Bitmap as a PNG image at 300dpi.  It seems that even if I use SetResolution() to set the dpi before calling save, when I open the image in paint it reports 96dpi.

```
MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Bitmap bitmap = rasterizer.GetCrop(
                GraphicHelpers.GetRelativeRectangle(tile, size.Width, size.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
{
    using (Bitmap drawing = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height))
    {
        drawing.SetResolution(300, 300);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawing))
        {
            g.DrawImage(drawing, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            drawing.Save(targetStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using SetResolution() then just calling save specifying ImageFormat.Png but that didn't seem to work either.

What is necessary to create a 300dpi png using GDI?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
Single rapportRes = 300 / 96; //where 96 is standard screen resolution
MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Bitmap bitmap = rasterizer.GetCrop(GraphicHelpers.GetRelativeRectangle(tile, int(size.Width*rapportRes), int(size.Height*rapportRes)), PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
    {
        using (Bitmap drawing = new Bitmap(int(bitmap.Width*rapportRes), int(bitmap.Height*rapportoRes)))
        {
            drawing.SetResolution(300, 300);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawing))
            {
                g.DrawImage(drawing, new Rectangle(0, 0, int(bitmap.Width*rapportRes), int(bitmap.Height*rapportoRes)), new Rectangle(0, 0, int(bitmap.Width*rapportRes), int(bitmap.Height*rapportoRes)), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                drawing.Save(targetStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that will cause the resolution of my image to be increased, the image I am saving needs to be 512X512 at 300 dpi, the code above still saves at 96dpi, just a higher resolution

Comment: Sorry, staying at this document the GDI+ in win7 with PNG are broken, I remember now I've used this code for bypass this problem: you may try as stated in this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62368caa-05f4-4798-9c59-5d82f881a97c/systemdrawingbitmapsetresolution-is-completely-broken-on-windows-7?forum=netfxbcl
quoting the part 
"Ok, I can confirm that specifying the ImageFormat.BMP does save the resolution settings..... "If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used."

Comment: I tried cloning and setting resolution then saving with no result, file still reports 96dpi

Comment: using ImageFormat.Bmp instead of ImageFormat.Png? I know you need a PNG but maybe if this works you can use this format